# How to handle different types of input in java

Tags: java, user-input

In this question

> Write a program which demonstrates **method overloading** having the following method:

```
1.Interest_rate*(int s, int a, float d)
2.Interest_rate*(float s, int a, float d)
3.Interest_rate*(int s, int a, double d)
```

> and these are the test cases which are based on the input format of the method:
>
> **Test Case 1**
>
> 1000  66  12.1f
>
> **Test Case 2**
>
> 1000f  45  12.1f

so how can I create the main function where the input will automatically trigger the desired function like in *test case 1, it should call the `1.Interest_rate`* and *test case 2 should call `2.Interest_rate`* and so on

Comment: Post whatever code you have written so far and let us know where you are stuck. Note that SO is not for completing your task; it's for helping you if you're stuck.

Comment: You need to read up on what [Method Overloading](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/method-overloading/) actually is. Then it will become clear to you. It's a lot easier than you think. You can have several methods with the same name providing the parameters signature is different in each method.

Comment: Case 1 and 3 are having equal formats, is the f in last case a typo?

Comment: @SamuelSilverMoos  yup, that was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I would recommend to use a Regex Matcher to sort input cases.**

> an integer can be detected as `-?\d+`
>
> a float like in your examples as `-?\d+(\.\d+)?f`
>
> a double as `-?\d+\.\d+`
>
> whitspace as `\s` one or more whitespaces `\s+`

may a research on Java Regex in generally could help.

**Next you have to understand what method overloading is.**

After some reasearch you will find out that it basically is that you can create multiple methodes with same name, but other inputs argument types.

If you have fully understud the upper topics, (plus how a scanner works) in generally, you can start implementing.

For the case you have done all this and still stuck, may following implementation to the question helps you. But as always: use only code you fully understand, else he will hit back.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerWithDifferentInputs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String input = sc.nextLine();
            if (input.matches("-?\\d+\\s+\\d+\\s+\\d+(\\.\\d+)?f")) {
                input.replace("f", "");
                String[] parts = input.split("\\s+");
                interestRate(Integer.parseInt(parts[0]), Integer.parseInt(parts[1]), Float.parseFloat(parts[2]));
            } else if (input.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?f\\s+\\d+\\s+\\d+(\\.\\d+)?f")) {
                input.replace("f", "");
                String[] parts = input.split("\\s+");
                interestRate(Float.parseFloat(parts[0]), Integer.parseInt(parts[1]), Float.parseFloat(parts[2]));
            } else if (input.matches("-?\\d+\\s+\\d+\\s+\\d+\\.\\d+")) {
                String[] parts = input.split("\\s+");
                interestRate(Integer.parseInt(parts[0]), Integer.parseInt(parts[1]), Double.parseDouble(parts[2]));
            } else if (input.equals("q")) {
                System.out.println("exit");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid Input");
            }
        }
    }

    static void interestRate(int i1, int i2, float f) {
        System.out.println("case int, int, float");
        System.out.println(i1 + " " + i2 + " " + f);
    }

    static void interestRate(float f1, int i, float f2) {
        System.out.println("case float, int, float");
        System.out.println(f1 + " " + i + " " + f2);
    }

    static void interestRate(int i1, int i2, double d) {
        System.out.println("case int, int, double");
        System.out.println(i1 + " " + i2 + " " + d);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets only consider the first two overloads. You have to check whether the first number provided to the program is a floating point number or an integer. According to your input definition you can do this like so:

```
if ( args[0].endsWith("f") )
  // First number is a float
  Interest_rate(Float.parseFloat(args[0]), Integer.parseInt(args[1]), Float.parseFloat(args[2]));
else
  // First number is an integer
  Interest_rate(Integer.parseInt(args[0]), Integer.parseInt(args[1]), Float.parseFloat(args[2]));
```

As you can see, in both cases we call a method `Interest_rate` but with different types. The compiler will select the correct overload.